# Contar frecuencia de cuatrogramas con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación, criptografía

estoy tratando de descifrar el siguiente texto: `PBFPVYFBQXZTYFPBFEQJHDXXQVAPTPQJKTOYQWIPBWLXTOXBTFXCQWAXBVCXQWAXFQJVWLEQNTOZQGGQLFXQWAKVWLXQWAEBIPBFXFQVXGTVJVWLBTPQWAEBFPBFHCVLXBQUFEWLXGDPEQVPQGVPPBFTIXPFHXZHVFAGFOTHFEFBQUFTDHZBQPOTHXTYFTODXQHFTDPTOGHFQPBQWAQJJTODXQHFOQPWTBDHHIXQVAPBFZQHCFWPFHPBFIPBQWKFABVYYDZBOTHPBQPQJTQOTOGHFQAPBFEQJHDXXQVAVXEBQPEFZBVFOJIWFFACFCCFHQWAUVWFLQHGFXVAFXQHFUFHILTTAVWAFFAWTEVDITDHFHFQAITIXPFHXAFQHEFZQWGFLVWPTOFFA`

(Está cifrado en inglés y ya sé lo que dice pero quiero descifrarlo yo mismo)

Para esto, estoy haciendo un análisis de las frecuencias de las palabras y quiero crear un programa en python que me cuente el número de palabras de 4 letras (cuatrogramas) que tienen mayor frecuencia en el texto y que las letras que componen el cuatrograma sean diferentes. Esto con la intensión de reemplazarla por "tion" que es una palabra común en inglés. Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Muchas gracias!

Yo ya he intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
v={}
for i in range(len(texto)-4+1):
    v[i]=texto[i:i+4]
print(range(len(texto)-4+1))
print(v)
for i in v:
    v[i]=set(v[i])
print(v)
w={}
for i in v:
    if len(v[i]) == 4:
        w[i]=v[i]
    else:
        w[i]='a'
print(w)
w=w.strip('a')
print(w)
```

primero creé un vector v, que es el vector de todas las posibles palabras de 4 letras y estoy tratando de eliminar de este vector palabras que tienen letras repetidas, para esto, creé un nuevo vector w, pero en la ultima parte me sale error, qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida (si no incluso puede acabar cerrada) deberías incluir tus intentos por resolver el problema, a poder ser con algún fragmento de código, explicando en qué punto te has quedado atascado

Comment: @abulafia He intentado fraccionar el texto en todas las posibles letras de cuatro letras y contarlas, pero me parece que esto es dispendioso y requiere demasiado tiempo,pues pienso que se puede hacer de una forma más eficiente.

Comment: Mira las ideas que doy en mi respuesta a ver si te llevan a algún sitio

Comment: El código que has añadido tiene varios errores. Primero, estás creando diccionarios en vez de vectores (listas). Para que sean listas deberías usar `v=[]` y para añadirle elementos `v.append()`. Después, no deberías sustituir cada elemento de `v` por un set, sino que puedes ir aprovechando el primer bucle para meter en `v` sólo aquellos cuatrogramas que tengan letras diferentes. Para ello puedes hacer `cuatro=texto[i:i+4]` y despues `if len(set(cuatro))==4` lo metes a la lista. Finalmente no sé que pretendías con el strip, pero el error es que eso no puedes hacerlo sobre un diccionario.

Answer (score 1):

## Ideas

> (Puedes intentar usar alguna de éstas y si no llegas a buen término editar tu pregunta para añadir hasta dónde conseguiste llegar)

- Separar tu cadena en cuatrogramas puede hacerse con una expresión generadora como esta:

  ```
  (txt[i:i+4] for i in range(len(txt)-4+1))
  ```
- Mirar si un cuatrograma tiene todas sus letras diferentes puede hacerse por ejemplo creando un conjunto (`set()`) a partir del cuatrograma, y viendo si el número de elementos de ese conjunto es igual a 4, pues un conjunto elimina automáticamente elementos repetidos (almacena sólo elementos diferentes). Inversamente, el cuatrograma tendrá letras repetidas si `len(set(cuatrograma)) != 4`. Con este tipo de condiciones y una comprensión de listas puedes filtrar para quedarte sólo con aquellos que tengan diferentes sus cuatro letras.
- Contar cuántas veces se repite cada cuatrograma puede hacerlo la clase `collections.Counter()`, así:

  ```
  contador = collections.Counter(filtrados)
  ```

  siendo `filtrados` la lista de cuatrogramas "supervivientes" del paso anterior.

  Este contador es un diccionario en el que cada clave es un cuatrograma y cada valor es cuántas veces aparece. Además tiene métodos como `contador.most_common(3)` por ejemplo, que te da los 3 más frecuentes en forma de lista de tuplas. En este caso por ejemplo daría `[('XQVA', 3), ('XQWA', 3), ('XQHF', 3)]`

Comment: Mire por favor mi edición de la pregunta.